# How to Search Urdu in Jquery Chosen Plugin?Is there another way to search urdu in Selectbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

Basically I want to have search option in select box with jquery chosen implemented on select box.All option are in Urdu Language.How can I expand chosen search to match Urdu?

Or there is another way to search Urdu in Select box?

any Other suggestion.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple method to apply all you RegEx logic(that one can apply easily in English) for any Language using Unicode.

For matching a range of Unicode Characters like all Alphabets [A-Za-z] we can use

> [\u0041-\u005A] where **\u0041** is Hex-Code for **A** and **\u005A** is Hex Code for **Z**

```
'matchCAPS leTTer'.match(/[\u0041-\u005A]+/g)
//output ["CAPS", "TT"]
```

In the same way we can use other Unicode characters or their equivalent Hex-Code according to their Hexadecimal Order *(eg: \u0A10 to \u0A1F)* provided by unicode.org

**Try**:

```
[ڀ-ڴ]
```

It will match all characters between ڀ and ڴ if provided by unicode.org in this order

**I don't know Arabic/Urdu :)**

**For matching:** you can easily get any plugin for English, modify it little bit with Urdu/Arabic chars and its done.

**For Ref:**

[Javascript regex insensitive turkish character issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964930/javascript-regex-insensitive-turkish-character-issue/23966236#23966236)

[Validate url for multilingual - Japanese langauga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077144/validate-url-for-multilingual-japanese-langauga/23998735#23998735)

[Multilingual email address validation with jQuery and RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774413/multilingual-email-address-validation-with-jquery-and-regex/23875597#23875597)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Harpreet Singh..Your idea worked perfect for me..I have successfully implement search in drop down after 2 hour work..Yahooooooooo no i can search Urdu or any other language.Thanks a lot again for help.

Comment: @KashifR, Even I am feeling great for helping a Pakistani Brother on Stackoverflow. Thanks for accepting.

Comment: Again Thanks Paa G @Harpreet Singh