# How to include ё in [а-я] regexp char interval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, rails-i18n

Russian alphabet includes the letter `ё`, which was undeservedly forgotten at beggining of computing.

So, if i want to use a regexp with character diapason, I must mention this letter separately:

```
[а-яА-яёЁ]
```

instead of:

```
[а-яА-Я]
```

example:

lets we have string "Верёвочка - 12" and need to parse only word by regular expression:

```
word = "Верёвочка"[/а-яА-Я/]   # => ""
word = "Верёвочка"[/а-яА-ЯёЁ/] # => "Верёвочка"
```

How can I upgrade regexp class in Ruby or Ruby on Rails to resolve this problem?

Comment: Cannot parse your sentence "instead simplest".

Comment: What does "instead: `[а-яА-Я]`" mean?

Comment: This link may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469916/how-to-search-urdu-in-jquery-choosen-pluginis-there-another-way-to-search-urdu/24470084#24470084

Comment: @sawa: "instead" -> "instead of". The question is about "including" a character into the range `а-я` by default.

Comment: @Blender I see. That could be the case.

Comment: @Harpreet Singh: Blender is much closer. Default include of 'ё' to interval [а-я] needed.

Comment: I'm not a Rubyist, but Unicode has character classes that include letters in many languages but not space/punctuation--`\p{Word}` is one I see suggested out there. That will match not only `[а-я]` but `[a-z]`, etc. too.

Comment: @sawa: i'd corrected this. (instead)

Comment: @twotwotwo You seem to be right. This looks like an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: `/[[:alpha:]]+/` would work, too

Answer (score 2):

The original `/а-яА-Я/` and `/а-яА-ЯёЁ/` patterns just match sequences of literal chars, `а-яА-Я` and `а-яА-ЯёЁ` strings respectively, since the char ranges are not enclosed with `[` and `]` that would form a character class. Even if they were, without a quantifier, that would only match a single char that falls within the range(s).

To match a sequence of one or more Russian letters, you need either of:

```
/[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+/
/[а-яё]+/i
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/lPq7gRJUXR)

Note that there is *NO* Unicode category class like `\p{Russian}`, and `\p{Cyrillic}` matches all Cyrillic chars, not just the Russian ones. The letter `Ёё` does not fall into the range between `а-я` and `А-Я` and **must be added "manually", see the [Unicode table](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0400-04FF):

[image]

And here is the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/jIDTKv):

```
s = "Верёвочка - 12"
puts s[/[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+/] # => Верёвочка
puts s[/[а-яё]+/i]    # => Верёвочка
```

Comment: Commenting to add that /[ЁА-яё]+/ follows Unicode code point order, which makes it very nice for (Unicode-aware) programmers to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Is one, but not are beatifull decision: use `[/а-ё/]` instead of `[/а-яё/]`. This worked, but letter not in proper direction:

```
str = "верёвочка"
str[/^[а-ё]+$/]
#=> "верёвочка"
```

Comment: This solution is not right. Have a look at my answer to see (I posted a table) where it goes wrong.

Comment: Can't find anything.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. [My solution](https://ideone.com/jIDTKv) is the correct one to find any chunk of 1+ Russian letters. Your `/^[а-ё]+$/` only finds a match if the whole line consists of 1 or more chars that are one of `абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяѐё` letters. Note that `ѐ` is not a Russian letter, and that regex of yours does not even match uppercase Russian letters.

Answer (score 0):

This is cool - I had never thought that much about character ranges in unicode.

It seems that for some reason А-я were encoded in the unicode range 0x410 to 0x44f, but some other characters (such as ё) were added in 0x400 to 0x410 and then 0x450 to 0x45f ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode) has a full breakdown of what characters went where)

As a consequence, /[Ѐ-ё]/ should work, but might feel quite illogical to a native speaker.

You can of course do raw unicode escapes, i.e. `/[\u0400-\u045f]/` (or up until \u04ff if you want the full cyrillic block) but that does make you either remember that (or assign it to some constant for future use).

Lastly, you can refer to entire scripts with

```
/\p{Cyrillic}/
```

although my understanding is that this includes more characters, such as Ԧ

Comment: Yes, i seek a human readable decision, like[а-я].   /\p{Cyryllic}/ not working in Ruby: SyntaxError: (pry):2: invalid character property name {Cyrillic}: /\p{Cyrillic}/

Comment: Worked for me (ruby 2.0.0). The regexp engine in ruby has changed quite a bit between versions.

Comment: It's also includes some non russian characters like `Ѐ`